# Only edges show in edit mode

Tags: modeling, edges

I'm following donut tutorial on Youtube.
I have problem in edit mode. When I enter it, instead of showing every face, edge and vertex it only shows those at end and only those can be edited.
Mentor on YT selected those then hide other with Invert select and then Hide, but everything I try it does not change.

[image]

Comment: Turn off the visibility of the modifiers in Edit Mode (may be the solidify enough). You can do it by pressing the little, blue square icon near modifier's name.

Comment: That is. I now remeber he unchecked to do something and probably I didn't see when he check it on again. Thank you!